# what are these tmpfs partitions/folders for and how to remove them?

Tags: linux, partitioning

I am running Fedora 20. I got the following output for the `$df -h`

```
$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   11G  8.0G  2.1G  80% /
devtmpfs                 3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.5G   76K  3.5G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.5G  676K  3.5G   1% /run
tmpfs                    3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    3.5G  164K  3.5G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                477M   90M  358M  20% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home   45G   26G   17G  60% /home
none                     224G  114G  111G  51% /media/sf_VBShared
```

I don't why there are few `tmpfs` and the `devtmpfs`. And why they are here? Can I remove them and get these disk space back?

Comment: They don't occupy any disk space.

Comment: @KeithThompson do you think this is quite exhaustive answer?

Comment: @ArtemNovikov: Are you asking about my comment or about one of the answers?

Comment: @KeithThompson about your comment. It doesn't explain what issue the author has. I know you posted just a comment, not an answer, but still, would be better if you provided a more detailed answer (if you have it).

Comment: @ArtemNovikov: I posted it as a comment (three years ago) because it wasn't a complete answer. JdeBP's answer seems reasonably complete.

Answer (score 11):

The comment and the other answer have addressed your misconceptions about tmpfs.  Here, I'm going to address

> Why they are here?

and

> Can I remove them?

as asked.

All of these are, in systemd slang, *API filesystems*.  They are fundamental to the operation of a systemd-based system, and the systemd program mounts them at system initialization, before it does pretty much anything else.  The `system-manager` from [nosh](https://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/) does much the same, excepting (currently) `/sys/fs/cgroup` and `/tmp`.

## `/dev/shm`

On (only) Debian Linux operating systems, this is actually `/run/shm`. This tmpfs has the specific purpose of implementing *POSIX shared memory* on your operating system.  Removing it will cause applications that use POSIX shared memory to fail.

## `/sys/fs/cgroup`

This is where systemd (and others) mount the various *control group* control hierarchies that are available on your operating system.  Removing it will stop the parts of your operating system, that depend from control groups, working.

## `/tmp`

This is of course the place where users expect to be able to put short-stay temporary files.  Removing it will make a fair number of applications that use temporary files quite unhappy.

## `/run`

This used to be `/var/run`.  It is where (specific kinds of) temporary files that can potentially last until the next system bootstrap are placed.  You'll find this full of PID files, the systemd non-persistent journal, UNIX-domain sockets, FIFOs, and other similar things.  Removing it will make the systemd journal cry; break the (mis-)management of a depressingly large number of dæmons that still, even today, use PID files; and wreck udev, the systemd "multi-seat" system, and a whole bunch of other subsystems.

On a nosh system, removing it will similarly break all of those same subsystems with their FIFOs and sockets.  It will also break the service manager's control API, the service manager's associated logger dæmon, and the control/status APIs of any "early supervise" dæmons.

## `/dev`

This is where, conventionally, all of the device files for character and block devices are stored on Unices and on Linux.  A lot of programs and subsystems expect conventional names like `/dev/tty`, `/dev/null`, `/dev/zero`, `/dev/console`, `/dev/fd/0`, `/dev/sda`, and so forth to work.  Removing this will break so much of your system that I doubt that it will be usable at all.  This is a `devtmpfs` rather than a `tmpfs`.  The difference is that the former is automatically populated and de-populated with device file entries by the kernel itself, as devices are loaded/enabled and disabled/unloaded in the kernel.

## Further reading

- [`system-manager`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/system-manager.html).  Section 8.  nosh manual pages.
- [*API FileSystems*](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/).  Freedesktop.org.
- [*File system hierarchy overview*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html).  Freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering (2011).  [*/var/run and /var/lock on tmpfs*](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/var-run-tmpfs).  Fedora Project.
- Lennart Poettering (2011-03-30). [*What's this /run directory doing on my system and where does it come from?*](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-March/150031.html)  Fedora Development mailing list.
- [`/var/run`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARRUNRUNTIMEVARIABLEDATA).  Filesystem Hierarchy Standard.  2.3.  pathname.com.
- [`/tmp`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/tmp.html).  Linux Filesystem Hierarchy.  The Linux Documentation Project.
- [*Why put `/dev/shm` and `/tmp` under `/run`?*](https://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory#Why_put_.2Fdev.2Fshm_and_.2Ftmp_under_.2Frun.3F).  ReleaseGoals.  Debian.

Comment: But how is it possible to have multiple entires for tempfs? Logically that means `/dev/shm` clashes with everything from `/run`. But in reality they don't and they even have different contents. How does that happen if both are mapped to the same device? I've seen this with other file systems as well.

Comment: That is a different question, and _not_ the questions that are asked here.  You know where [ask] is.  (-:

Answer (score 0):

tmpfs is in short (a sort of) ramdisk. The ideea is not to trash the hard drive with small temporary stuff, nowadays that memory is no longer a premium, with the added speed bonus of a ram based block device.

In long you can read for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

To quote from the article

Everything stored in tmpfs is temporary in the sense that no files will be created on the hard drive; however, swap space is used as backing store in case of low memory situations. On reboot, everything in tmpfs will be lost.

The memory used by tmpfs grows and shrinks to accommodate the files it contains and can be swapped out to swap space.

Comment: Additionnaly, tmpfs is way faster in terms of read/write and access time.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to understand what is tmpfs, I'd suggest checking the kernel.org(link at the bottom) first.

Tmpfs is a file system which keeps all files in virtual memory(physical memory+swap). That as per the documentation: if the tmpfs instance is removed, then everything stored therein is lost.

If you try to force unmount the fs when is mounted, the system should not let you as can see from the below example, the files keep in /dev/shm belong to the OS, which means it would crash the processes using this resource. Alternatively comment the lines from /etc/fstab is neither a good idea, because virtual filesystems such as procfs or sysfs could not work as expected, or even being mounted.

```
[root@client ~]# mount |egrep tmpfs
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
[root@client ~]# for pid in $(fuser -m /dev/shm 2>/dev/null|sed "s/m//g");do echo $pid--;pstree -p $pid ;done
2194--
gnome-settings-(2194)───{gnome-settings}(2197)
2210--
metacity(2210)───{metacity}(11132)
2253--
pulseaudio(2253)─┬─gconf-helper(2263)
                 ├─{pulseaudio}(2260)
                 └─{pulseaudio}(2262)
2264--
gnome-volume-co(2264)
2267--
gpk-update-icon(2267)───{gpk-update-ico}(2870)
```

[Kernel - tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)